# unity webgl scale page on different sizes of internet browsers on pc or phone

Tags: unity, html5, webgl

unity only has a fixed resolution for building webgl. how can I make it changebale on users browser size change.

there are some tutorials on the internet that doesn't match. there is only

> > index.html unityloader.js
> >     gamename.json  gamename.data.unityweb  gamename.asm.memory.unityweb
> >     gamename.framework.unityweb  gamename.asm.code.unityweb

how can I make multi res webgl output happen for unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[change the HTML as documented here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html). You can choose either one of the defaults or create your own template.

According to those docs you create folder in `Assets` called `WebGLTemplates` and inside that create a new folder for your template like `BetterTemplate`. Inside that put an `index.html` file and any other images, css, JavaScript files you want included with your game.

The index.html could look something like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>%UNITY_WEB_NAME%</title>
    <style>
      body { margin: 0; }
      #gameContainer { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
      canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
    </style>
    <script src="Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
    var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "Build/dist.json");
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="gameContainer"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Then you pick Edit->Project Settings->Player from the menus and under the WebGL tab choose your template

[image]

[Here's an example](https://github.com/greggman/better-unity-webgl-template).